# Apply an update to a queryset involving a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have something like the code below, where I can nicely apply the update method to change the `engine` type of the cars contained in the query set `vintage_cars`. Is it possible to use update in a similar fashion for the code using the for loop, where a foreign key is involved?

```py
class Driver(Model):
    name = CharField()
    licence = CharField()

class Car(Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)
    status = CharField()
    type = CharField()
    engine = CharField()


vintage_cars = Car.objects.filter(type="vintage")
vintage_cars.update(engine="gas")

for c in vintage_cars:
    driver = c.driver
    if driver and driver.licence not in VALID_LICENCES:
        c.driver = None
        c.status = "IMPOUNDED"
    d.save()
```

I'm thinking I need to apply a second filter involving this clause:

```
if driver and driver.licence not in VALID_LICENCES:
```

to `vintage_cars`, but I'm not sure if that makes sense in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you can not use a filter on a related object, because then an `UPDATE` clause is not possible. You can however use an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

vintage_cars = Car.objects.filter(type='vintage')
vintage_cars.update(engine='gas')
vintage_cars.filter(
    Exists(
        Driver.objects.filter(~Q(license__in=VALID_LICENCES), car=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
).update(driver=None, status='IMPOUNDED')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little confused by car=OuterRef('pk'). What is "car". I would have expected "driver" to be used in some way as this is the name of the ForeignKey field. Lets say Car also has the field "previous_driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)" but I am only interest in "driver", which can be None.

Comment: @Baz: we here filter the `Driver` objects, such that we select the `Driver` which has as `Car` the one from the "outer" `QuerySet`, so in this case the `Car`s that we want to filter.

Comment: @Baz: the main reason why we need to work with a subquery is because SQL does *not* allow an `UPDATE table JOIN othertable`, since then it is ambiguous what table to update.